# Redirecting standard input

Tags: c

If you're redirecting input for a compiled c program, what's the typical method of reading this input within the program. Is it simply scanf? Say you have a text file like the following:

```
1
2
3
4
```

With 4 numbers, one on each line. How do you redirect standard input in your program to read this file, and duplicate it to another text file? Is each new line sent through scanf?

Answer (score 1):

Redirection of streams is an *OS* concept, it has nothing to do with the **C** language. If you read from `stdin`, which is the *standard input stream*, you will deal with it correctly. Functions like `scanf` use `stdin` implicitly, so your program will work fine regardless of whether it gets its input from the console or from a redirected file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, redirection is very easy. If you executable name is `a.out`

```
$ echo `a.out` > file.txt
```

will redirect all output from `a.out` to `file.txt`